# Sharing local user's profile picture with others in WinRT in local network game

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime

I am working on a WinRT app that is a local network playable game.  I can read the user's DisplayName, and AccountPicture within the app, and display them both locally to the user via xaml.  I am using the following code to get the account picture into a BitmapImage for binding within the xaml page:

```
private async Task<BitmapImage> GetDisplayImage()
    {
        BitmapImage image = null;

        if (CoreApplication.MainView != null)
        {
            await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                {
                    var stream = await Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetAccountPicture(Windows.System.UserProfile.AccountPictureKind.LargeImage).OpenReadAsync();
                    image = new BitmapImage();
                    image.SetSource(stream);
                });
        }
        return image;
    }
```

I thought that it would be possible to read the stream into a byte array, and ship it when the app connects to others, and then reconstitute the byte array on the other end like so:

```
public static async Task<byte[]> ToArray(this IRandomAccessStream stream)
    {
        IBuffer buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer((uint)stream.Size);
        await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, buffer.Capacity, InputStreamOptions.ReadAhead);
        await stream.FlushAsync();
        return buffer.ToArray();
    }
```

However, on the line:

```
await stream.FlushAsync();
```

I am receiving an UnauthorizedAccessException:

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

It must be possible to share the profile pic with others, because I see it done elsewhere, but I cannot seem to find any information on how to do this.  If anyone could point me in the right direction on this (I wonder if there is a different api I need to hook into, or if I need to set something in the App manifest..), I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could directly read the `IStorageFile` returned by `GetAccountPicture`:

```
var file = UserInformation.GetAccountPicture(AccountPictureKind.LargeImage);
var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
var bytes = buffer.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with the code you posted, the app just hangs on the line: var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
Is there something special about the AccountPicture file?

Comment: I spoke too soon, I had a different thread that was running for some testing that was causing the deadlock, your code worked perfectly. Thanks!